# How to use a piece of code to handle all Http requests on Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to customize the request processing flow myself. I don't want to use the Controller under Asp.net core to process the request. But there is a premise that there must be a class method or a delegate (containing Request and response formal parameters), where all requests are processed

For response processing, I hope to use Asp.net core's default response processing method (if it can be done), such as Ajax requests, dynamic page output, response pictures, file downloads, etc.

Envisioned code：

```
var handler=HTTP.handler((req, res) => {
  if(req.getHeader("x-requested-with")){
      if(req.para("username")==null){
         res.endError(403)
      }else{
         res.statusCode = 200;
         res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
         res.end('Hello World');
      }

  }else{
        res.view('/test/index.cshtml');
  }

});
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a controller?

Comment: No, I want to use a Controller, but the development freedom of the Controller in Asp.Net Core does not meet my development needs. I want to use my custom Controller to handle client requests.

Comment: If I want to use my custom Controller, but Asp.net core must provide a component, execute a piece of code to dispatch all requests (this code can be a delegate or class) to my custom Controller

Answer (score 0):

You want to write custom middleware. It can be registered in Startup to be called as a part of request processing and will be called for all requests.

There is a HttpContext object so you can get access to the current request.

The docs have some good examples that you can modify.

[Custom middleware documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write)

Comment: How to set the response information in the HTTPResponse field of HttpContext? Output String or IActionResult to the requesting client?

Comment: Although I want to customize the request processing flow, but in response to the client's request, I hope to continue to use the existing response methods of Asp.Net-Core, but I don't know how to use them in custom middleware?